# An intuitive way to understand MARGIN in sweep and apply

Tags: r, apply

I have always been confused by how MARGIN seems to mean 2 different things in `sweep` and `apply`. Consider:

```
m <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)
# The "- 1" operation is applied to all cells in each row
sweep(m, MARGIN = 1, 1, "-")
# The sum operation is applied to each column
apply(m, MARGIN = 1, sum)
```

Do you have a mnemonic device to understand this seemingly contradictory meaning of MARGIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MARGIN argument means exactly the same thing in both functions and that is row-wise operation. I have been confused with `sweep` many times in the past but I think you are confused with `apply`.

I am printing the matrix below so that it is easy to visually compare with `apply` and `sweep` later on:

```
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

First of all the `sweep` function does a row-wise operation when MARGIN is 1. I will slightly change the third argument so that this is more obvious:

```
> sweep(m, MARGIN = 1, 1:3, "-")
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    3
[2,]    0    3
[3,]    0    3
```

In the above case number 1 was deducted from row 1, number 2 from row 2 and number 3 from row 3. So, clearly this is a row-wise operation.

Now let's see below the `apply` function:

```
> apply(m, MARGIN = 1, sum)
[1] 5 7 9
```

Clearly, the matrix has 3 rows and 2 columns. It is easy to imply that this is also a row-wise operation since we have 3 results i.e. the same as the number of rows. This is also confirmed if we check the numbers. Row 1 sums to 5, row 2 to 7 and row 3 to 9.

So, clearly MARGIN in both cases implies a row-wise operation.

Comment: You're using row-wise in two different senses across the two functions, so MARGIN is indeed inconsistent. Please see the example in my answer.

To elaborate: For `sweep()` you mean in the sense of `numpy.sum(m, axis=MARGIN)`, but for `apply()` it actually uses the proper (statistical) definition of `MARGIN` which is the *opposite* of a `numpy` axis.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding Inconsistency & LyzandeR's Answer**:
*First of all OP you are correct they are indeed inconsistent!*

**Here is concrete proof/example of inconsistency:**

Did you know that apply & sweep can be used to do the same thing?
Well here's what happens when you do that:

```
(A = matrix(1:9, 3))
(B=sweep(A, MARGIN=1, 1:3, FUN='-'))
(C=apply(A, MARGIN=2, 1:3, FUN='-'))
stopifnot(all(B==C))
# ^ No error they are equal! but MARGINS are opposite!!
```

Explicitly the output is:

```
> (A = matrix(1:9, 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

```
> (B=sweep(A, MARGIN=1, 1:3, FUN='-'))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    3    6
[2,]    0    3    6
[3,]    0    3    6
```

```
> (C=apply(A, MARGIN=2, 1:3, FUN='-'))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    3    6
[2,]    0    3    6
[3,]    0    3    6
```

The simple fact is that `apply(A, MARGIN=1, ..., FUN=f)` means: copy & apply FUN to each *row* of A, & `sweep(A, MARGIN=1, ..., FUN=f)` means: copy & apply FUN to each *column* of A.

**My Mnemonic**:
I use `apply()` with *negative MARGINs* (that is `apply(A, MARGIN=2, ...)` becomes --> `apply(A, MARGIN=-1, ...)`), this makes the behavior consistent with sweep (in terms of absolute values) & has the added benefit of making the MARGIN argument consistent with the numpy/torch/matlab axis arguments!! e.g., `torch.mean(arr, axis=0)` == `np.mean(arr, axis=0)` == `apply(arr, MARGIN=-1, mean)` (save of course R's base-1 indexing)

It is easy to remember because *you cannot actually use negative MARGINs with* `sweep()`! So if you forget which function needs them it will immediately remind you with an error. ...Also negative numbers come before positive numbers just like (A)pply comes before (S)weep in the alphabet.